# How to make SearchView collapse after making a query in Android

Tags: android, searchview

I'm using SearchView to send a query from one Activity to another. When i press BackButton from the search activity and return to the callee activity the SearchView is focused and expanded and i would like not to be like that.

I already tried to use

```
setOnQueryTextListener(...)
{
   searchView.clearFocus();
   searchView.setQuery(null, false);
   searchView.setIconofied(true);
}
```

This will work great if the query is with the Enter button but won't work if the query is with a suggestion.

Is anyway to lose focus and reset SearchView state?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by making the Activity to do query to itself, and then calling the search activity with an Intent

http://blog.dpdearing.com/2011/05/getting-android-to-call-onactivityresult-after-onsearchrequested/